# Custom date formatting in javascript (ES6)

Tags: javascript

We have an API that accepts a date string as argument in the format:

```
2020-11-30
```

When we have a date object it's very easy in PowerShell to achieve the correct format:

```
(Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Doing this in javascript is a bit more difficult

```js
date.toISOString() // 2020-10-28T00:00:00.000Z
```

How can to get rid of the time part in the string? Is there a better way to format a date in a custom matter?

Comment: take a look at the moment librarry

Comment: There are [~20k questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+format+date+is%3Aq) about formatting dates in JS already, have you done any research?

Comment: `date.toISOString().slice(0, 10)`

Answer (score -1):

Using the `moment` library you can format the date in many different ways, like here for example:

```
moment().format('YYYY MM DD');
```

[Moment Website](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score -2):

If you just want the date part, `date.toDateString()` is the answer for you;
if you're looking for some common solution, maybe you should try some libs like `momentjs` or `dayjs`(more lightweight).